# C# rule for public fields

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, public

I have problem with public fields, which I use from time to time in my code. I keep forgeting to change them to private and create properties for them- especialy when Im testing some new part of code (and Im used to create public field for testing at first).

I was thinking that it would be fine to see some sort of "warning" if I use public field in my code.

I have found out, that I can create a ruleset (Im using Visual Studio Community 2013) and choose any of the rule I need. I searched for the rules relative to public fields and found these 2: CA2211: Non-constant fields should not be visible  and CA1051: Do not declare visible instance fields. I checked these in the ruleset, tried to Run code analysis on whole solution but I cant see any warnings in the outcome.

I even tried to add something like `public int i;` in one of my classes but still nothing.

Do you know if I have the right rules or whether there is something else I should do to get the warning? Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend to validate your application with MS FXcop. this has all the rules available to write a standard code.

Comment: @RohitPrakash: FXCop is the old name for what is now called Code Analysis (and is integrated with Visual Studio).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Thanks for this great info. I think he can go with the Default code analysis in that case.

Comment: The problem I might have is that I somehow can not bind that new ruleset to my solution. Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264949.aspx  they say to just click on Analyze>Configure Code Analysis for "yourRulesetName" , but I only have options "Configure Code Anallysis for Solution" and  "Configure Code Anallysis for "myProjectName"

Comment: In addition, you could train yourself to always use [auto properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb384054.aspx).

Comment: If you right-click on your project from the Solution Explorer and choose "Properties", there should be an item "Code Analysis" on the left. Pick that, check "Enable Code Analysis on Build", then choose an item from "run this rule set".

Comment: I am using VS2012 and I see the both warnings.

Comment: @Corak, until C# 6.0 you can't set value of auto property, so it can't replace field. Regarding issue, I am using VS2013 express and I don't have this warning too, just checked. It could be, what it only works with full VS.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Mostert thank you, that solved the issue! :) Problem was I was trying to set it up in Solution properties, which was not working (I did not see the ruleset there) but in project properties, I can selectet "Browse" and choose my own ruleset.

Comment: @Sinatr - agreed. Replace "always" with "wherever possible". ^_^